# How to Parse Json in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio-2010

I am working in C#. I want to parse JSON in my application. But have no idea how to parse Json. I have search a lot on Google But couldn't find enough material. 
My JSOn  is ..

```
[{"id":"267","name":"Macmillan Nursing Service","telephone":"01595 743347",
"addr1":"Gilbert Bain Hospital","town":"Shetland","postcode":"ZE1 0TB",
"lat":"60.1505513","lng":"-1.1546642","distance":"3278.42778426762"},

{"id":"355","name":"Orkney Macmillan House","telephone":"01856 888249",
"addr1":"Balfour Hosptial","town":"","postcode":"KW15 1BH","lat":"58.9767143",
"lng":"-2.9649377","distance":"3421.52913012431"},

{"id":"57",
"name":"Community Macmillan Nurse","telephone":"01779 482568",
"addr1":"Peterhead Health    Centre","town":"Peterhead",
"postcode":"AB422XA","lat":"57.5034159","lng":"-1.7939854",
"distance":"3425.64696427705"},

{"id":"287","name":"Macmillan
Service","telephone":"01955 880397","addr1":"Caithness
General Hospital","town":"Wick","postcode":"KW1 5NS","lat":"58.4415",
"lng":"-3.09651","distance":"3452.34795736445"},

{"id":"288","name":"Macmillan Service",
"telephone":"01888 564015","addr1":"The Health Centre","town":"Banff","postcode":"AB45  
1HY","lat":"57.6686963","lng":"-2.5256111","distance":"3457.45181828202"}]
```

I am stuck in this work kindly help me out..

Any help would be great. Or a little clue about how to parse Json will also be enough.

Comment: What do you mean, "remotely"?  What is local and what is remote in this instance?

Comment: What do you mean by "Parse JSON remotely"?  I think your wording may be misleading if what you want to do is download a JSON string and then work with it locally...

Comment: well i just want to access this json from internet here is the link ..http://www.myhealthpal.com/charity_app/hospice.php?lat=57.155313&lan=57.155313&q=0

Comment: You can use the JSON.Net library. Or DataContractJsonSerializer in C#.

Comment: this Json is coming from internet and i want to show it in a list or gridview

Comment: and also want to store it in Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to de-serialise  a JSON string to an object.  You can create create a class that represents the object, and then de-serialise the json to it.

Something like

```
class Information
{
   int id;
   string name;
   string telephone;
   // etc
}
```

Then de-serialise with something like this

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
// Using List<T> as the JSON is organised like an array
List<Information> info = (List<Information >)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(JSONFeed);
```

Where `JSONFeed` is your json string from the website.

For a more indepth aproach see - [Tutorial on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C)

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for I have made the class already but couldn't know how to extract data from website ..

Comment: Are you not able to download the data? That is a different question from what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Use a brilliant [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library.

> Features
>
> ```
> Flexible JSON serializer for converting between .NET objects and JSON
> LINQ to JSON for manually reading and writing JSON
> High performance, faster than .NET's built-in JSON serializers
> Write indented, easy to read JSON
> Convert JSON to and from XML
> Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight and Windows Phone
> ```
>
> The serializer is a good choice when the JSON you are reading or
>   writing maps closely to a .NET class.
>
> LINQ to JSON is good for situations where you are only interested in
>   getting values from JSON, you don't have a class to serialize or
>   deserialize to, or the JSON is radically different from your class and
>   you need to manually read and write from your objects.

Comment: Well this answer doesn't seems enough .. Because i have already read it out.. I want a little coding if someone can ...

Comment: @BurhanMughal How is this answer not enough? You stated you do not know how to parse JSON, Jakub provided information regarding a popular library for doing just that, Parsing JSON.

Comment: I was jsut looking the answer like the Answer from Kami.. Thanx anyway to Jakub ..

Comment: @BurhanMughal - Have you clicked on the link provided? There is a sample there... and a performance comparison with `JavaScriptSerializer`

Comment: @ Well brother Just consider me the nieve user and u may come to know that waht I m Looking for.